# このjQueryのコードをネイティブのjavascriptで書くとどうなりますか?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/',
    type: 'get',
    async: false,
    success: function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery での実装が知りたいという事であれば、下記サイトでソースを閲覧できます。
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.ajax

簡易的に同様の事を行うには、XMLHttpRequest を用いて以下の様にします。

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        // success
        console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
    }
};

httpRequest.open('GET', '/ajax/', false);
httpRequest.send(null);
```